# Green's theorem, evaluating an integral over an ellipse

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: IMG]

For part (b) how do I evaluate the integral $\displaystyle \int \int_D f(x,y) \; dx \: dy$ ?

Answer (score 0):

use part (a) to replace the integral with one round the boundery. On the boundery $x = acos(\theta)$ and $y = bsin(\theta)$. Now get

1. A formula for $ds^2 = dx^2+dy^2$ in terms of $\theta$ and $d\theta$
2. the line integral as an integral over $\theta$ for $\theta$ from 0 to $2\pi$

the integral you get is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

By part a), and by parameterising $x = a\cos(t)$ and $y = b\sin(t)$, you have that since $r'(t) = (x'(t), y'(t))$ that $|r'(t)|^2 = [x'(t)]^2 + [y'(t)]^2 = a^2\sin^2(t) + b^2\cos^2(t)$ the integral is equivalent to $$\int_{[0, 2\pi]} \sqrt{b^2\cdot \cos^2(t) + a^2\cdot \sin^2(t)}\cdot |r'(t)| dt \\ = \int_{[0, 2\pi]} b^2\cos^2(t) + a^2\sin^2(t) dt \\ = 2\pi\cdot (1/2)\cdot( a^2 + b^2)= \pi\cdot(a^2+b^2)$$.